# Xcode Inspectors right side pane Attributes helper gone

Tags: xcode, swiftui, xcode14

I am using Xcode 14.3.1 and accidentally managed to hit a keyboard shortcut that disabled the `Attributes` column (the one which helps me setting e.g. font, padding and width in `SwiftUI`) in the right side Inspector pane. I have tried looking in `View > Inspectors` but the `Attributes` helper is gone from there too (see image).

[image]

How can I enable it again?

Answer (score 0):

Press this button (see image, the one left of the right pane toggle button) and click `Canvas`. `Attributes` will now appear again under `View > Inspectors`, as well as in the right side Inspectors pane.

[image]